# Postgres - how to encrypt a column and his data

Tags: sql, postgresql, encryption

I don't know if a similar question was asked before, but I didn't find what i need.
I have a table in Postgres database that contains a lot of rows and I need to encrypt one column of this table (and its relative data). In other questions found  was mentioned pgcrypto to encrypt columns, but in every example a brand new table is created and pgcrypto is used for INSERT statement and SELECT. Is possible to encrypt column and its preexisting data?
I hope everything is clear

Comment: You can  use `update`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pgcrypto module you can do it.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/encryption-options.html

There are some examples:

http://www.postgresonline.com/article_pfriendly/165.html