# How to encrypt Postgres 9.6 databse

Tags: postgresql

I have present my database and I have encrypt the complete database is there any way to encrypt database ? Version : Postgres 9.6

Comment: Use an encrypted filesystem?

Comment: I have encrypt the database then if anyone fire any query then data should show encrypted format

Comment: If you want to encrypt data on column level, you need to do that yourself, e.g. using [pgcrypto](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376605/encrypt-the-datas-in-postgresql

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42428360/postgresql-encrypt-column-with-pgcrypto

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50602705/postgres-how-to-encrypt-a-column-and-his-data

Comment: If I want to encrypt the complete database? is there any way?

Comment: How do you plan do decrypt the content? If everything is encrypted, then how do you maintain foreign keys? If the contents is decrypted, then how do you plan to search inside the content? What kind of threat are you expecting that can be prevented using encrypted data?